# package 'unrar-free' has no installation candidate xubuntu 20.03 (ubuntu based os)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, xubuntu, dpkg

hi everbody i've surfed the net alot but i could'nt get my answer,i've checked all the forums but no good result,please help me out with  this error i can't install any package even net-tools,please don't say have you done apt update,because i will do every single time
.
.
.
error : >>>>>>>>
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package rar is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'rar' has no installation candidate

Comment: So what about unrar or unrar-free, there's no candidate for them too.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Xubuntu 20.3." Details like that matter. If your description of the problem is inaccurate or incomplete, then we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's review how to find packages in the Ubuntu repositories.

---

First, let's look for `rar` using the [packages.ubuntu.com website](https://packages.ubuntu.com/). The web page for rar shows that the `rar` package does exist in the Ubuntu repositories, it's available for 20.04, and it's in the "multiverse" pocket:

[image: packages.ubuntu.com]

---

Next, let's look for "multiverse" in the Software & Updates control panel. In my example below, you can see the "multiverse" is unchecked. Check it.

[image: Software and Updates]

- You can find Software & Updates using your normal Desktop Search.

---

Finally, run `sudo apt update` because your sources changed.

Now rar and unrar will be installable for you.

unrar-free is slightly different. It's in "universe" instead of "multiverse". The process is the same; merely a different checkbox.

Comment: rmadison command not found, unfortunately

Comment: Try reading the answer again. It's changed.